# Use Wordpress loop to display thumbnail and excerpt

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I try to configure my loop to show my thumbnail next to a "read more" button and an excerpt. I have a quite okay view right now, but the problem is that the distance between the posts is not correct and if I use different text lenghts (e.g. less than 10 words), the result doesn't look good.
I used the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/37194017/6320176 to display the loop and my output code and my whole CSS looks like this:

```css
/* general */

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}
#site-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1024px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* main sections */

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 530px;
  padding: 2%;
}
#main {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#sidebar {
  width: 24%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#media {
  clear: both;
  height: 300px;
}
/* head section */

#logo {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 160px;
  height: 155px;
}
#row {
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(250, 250, 250);
  padding-left: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#navigation {
  font-decoration: none;
}
#navigation ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  text-align: center;
}
#navigation li {
  display: inline;
}
#navigation a {
  color: #454545;
  font-family: montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  -ms-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#navigation a:hover {
  color: #6990E8;
}
.distance {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
/* regelt den Abstand zwischen den Nav-Elementen */

/* featured */

#featured {
  background: #444444;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
/* text declaration */

p {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #2A2A2A;
}
a {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #828282;
  text-decoration: none;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  -ms-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #2A2A2A;
  font-weight: 300;
}
h2 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #2A2A2A;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  -ms-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
h2 a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #2A2A2A;
  font-weight: 300;
}
/* entry */

#thumbnail {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
/* footer area */

#footer-wrapper {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
#footer {
  background: #282828;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
#footer p {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  color: #B0B0B0;
  text-align: center;
}
#footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #B0B0B0;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  -ms-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}
#footer a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<main id="main">

  <article id="post">



    <!-- loop -->


    <div id="thumbnail">
      <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/M-Jiasmin-LeMeridien-0369-FINAL-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="M - Jiasmin LeMeridien 0369 FINAL" />
    </div>

    <h2><a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-6-the-last/">Beitrag 6</a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [&hellip;]</p>
    </div>
    <a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-6-the-last/">Weiterlesen...</a>


    <div id="thumbnail">
      <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/M-Jiasmin-LeMeridien-0293-FINAL-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="M - Jiasmin LeMeridien 0293 FINAL" />
    </div>

    <h2><a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-5-ohne-picture/">Beitrag 5</a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [&hellip;]</p>
    </div>
    <a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-5-ohne-picture/">Weiterlesen...</a>


    <div id="thumbnail">
      <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/M-Jiasmin-LeMeridien-0282-FINAL-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="M - Jiasmin LeMeridien 0282 FINAL" />
    </div>

    <h2><a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-4-servus/">Beitrag 4</a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [&hellip;]</p>
    </div>
    <a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-4-servus/">Weiterlesen...</a>


    <div id="thumbnail">
      <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/M-Jiasmin-LeMeridien-0524-FINAL-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="M - Jiasmin LeMeridien 0524 FINAL" />
    </div>

    <h2><a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-3-hi/">Beitrag 3</a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [&hellip;]</p>
    </div>
    <a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-3-hi/">Weiterlesen...</a>


    <div id="thumbnail">
      <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/M-Jiasmin-LeMeridien-0282-FINAL-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="M - Jiasmin LeMeridien 0282 FINAL" />
    </div>

    <h2><a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-2-hallo/">Beitrag 2</a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [&hellip;]</p>
    </div>
    <a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-2-hallo/">Weiterlesen...</a>


    <div id="thumbnail">
      <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/M-Jiasmin-LeMeridien-0524-FINAL-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="M - Jiasmin LeMeridien 0524 FINAL" />
    </div>

    <h2><a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-1-mut-interesante/">Beitrag 1</a></h2>
    <div class="entry">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [&hellip;]</p>
    </div>
    <a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-1-mut-interesante/">Weiterlesen...</a>


    <!-- end of the loop -->


  </article>

</main>
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: What is it exactly you want?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you are trying to achieve is commonly called the '[media object](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code)', an image with text next to it. This can nowadays be created using flexbox, an example can be viewed [here](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/media-object/).

Put every thumbnail, header, entry and hyperlink that belong to the same article in a wrapping element. Then follow the example from the link I mentioned above.

As a sidenote I noticed you are using `id="thumbnail"` while id's should only be used once per page, so instead rather use `class="thumbnail"`.

This is an example of how I would code your page.

HTML:

```
<article>
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/M-Jiasmin-LeMeridien-0369-FINAL-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="M - Jiasmin LeMeridien 0369 FINAL" />
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <h2><a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-6-the-last/">Beitrag 6</a></h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</p>
    <p><a href="http://localhost/2016/05/12/beitrag-6-the-last/">Weiterlesen...</a></p>
  </div>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
article {
  display: flex;
}

.entry {
  flex: 1;
}
```

This should prevent your layout from looking messy. Flexbox is great solution for these kinds of problems and is widely supported by browsers nowadays.